# Why is threading.Condition.notfiy_all not trigger that a waiting thread is continued?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

With the following code, I want to show how to synchronize with a thread.

- I want to have a separate thread that updates an image.
- From these images, I want to have an asynchronous generator.
- The images should only be updated when the asynchronous generator used it.
- The async generator should be waiting for a new image to be created.

Below, you find the code for that. It gets stuck waiting for the first image.

Why is the notify_all not releasing the image_created.wait?

```markdown
# Output
create new image
waiting for new image
start waiter
notify_all
wait for someone to take it
waiting for image_created
```

```py
import asyncio
import random
import threading
import time


class ImageUpdater:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.image_used = threading.Event()
        self.image_created = threading.Condition()

    def update_image(self):
        while True:
            self.image_used.clear()
            with self.image_created:
                print("create new image")
                time.sleep(0.6)
                self.image = str(random.random())
                print("notify_all")
                self.image_created.notify_all()
            print("wait for someone to take it")
            self.image_used.wait()
            print("someone took it")

    async def image_generator(self):
        def waiter():
            print("start waiter")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            with self.image_created:
                print("waiting for image_created")
                self.image_created.wait()
            print("waiter finished")
            self.image_used.set()

        while True:
            print("waiting for new image")
            await asyncio.to_thread(waiter)

            yield self.image


async def main():
    updater = ImageUpdater()

    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=updater.update_image)
    update_thread.start()

    async for image in updater.image_generator():
        print(f"Received new image: {image}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I found that when `self.image_created.notify_all()` is called, the async method is not waiting, so the method blocks when it gets there. I'm not sure what is really happening.

Comment: After moving self.image_used.set above the image_created.wait, it works just as expected. But I have no clue, why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `waiter`, the `__enter__` method of the context manager (`with self.image_created`) acquires `self.image_created`'s lock.  When you call `wait` the lock is released, and the thread will wait there until the other thread calls `self.image_created.notify`.  That never happens because the other thread is blocked, waiting for `self.image_used` to be set.  The two threads are deadlocked.

The context manager for `self.image_created` acquires the lock on entry to the `with:` block and releases it on exit.  So this code:

```
with self.image_created:
    self.image_created.wait()
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
self.image_created.acquire()  
# when you reach here, this thread owns the lock
self.image_created.wait()  # releases the lock
                           # waits for another thread to call notify
# You will never get this far since the other thread is blocked
self.image_created.release()
```

Instead of calling wait inside `with self.image_created`, you could just process the image and call `self.image_process.set()`.  That eliminates the call to `self.image_process.wait`, which is causing the deadlock.  But in that case you aren't using the functionality of the Condition object at all - you're just using it like another threading.Event.

This simpler program, which uses two Event objects to insure that the threads take turns, works:

```
import asyncio
import random
import threading
import time


class ImageUpdater:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.image_used = threading.Event()
        self.image_created = threading.Event()

    def update_image(self):
        while True:
            self.image_used.clear()
            print("create new image")
            time.sleep(0.6)
            self.image = str(random.random())
            print("new image created")
            self.image_created.set()
            print("wait for someone to take it")
            self.image_used.wait()
            print("someone took it")

    async def image_generator(self):
        def waiter():
            print("start waiter")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("waiting for image_created")
            self.image_created.wait()
            self.image_created.clear()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            self.image_used.set()    

        while True:
            print("waiting for new image")
            await asyncio.to_thread(waiter)

            yield self.image

async def main():
    updater = ImageUpdater()

    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=updater.update_image)
    update_thread.start()

    async for image in updater.image_generator():
        print(f"Received new image: {image}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.run(main())
```

You said that you eventually wanted to have more than one thread processing the images, so perhaps a producer-consumer architecture would be cleaner in the long run.  See quamrana's answer.

Comment: I ended up using an all async solution and use ayncio.to_thread for the most CPU-heavy computations. I am not sure, if that's better and it's probably premature optimization. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which uses a queue to synchronise the producer and consumer(s):

```
import asyncio
import random
import threading
import queue
import time

class ImageUpdater:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = queue.Queue(1)

    def update_image(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.6)
            print('Creating new image')
            image = str(random.random())
            self.q.put(image)

    async def image_generator(self):
        while True:
            print("waiting for new image")
            image = self.q.get()
            yield image

async def main():
    updater = ImageUpdater()

    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=updater.update_image)
    update_thread.start()


    async for image in updater.image_generator():
        print(f"Received new image: {image}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Sample output:

```
waiting for new image
Creating new image
Received new image: 0.004152636324671333
waiting for new image
Creating new image
Received new image: 0.23799099029083715
waiting for new image
Creating new image
Received new image: 0.17644888185774932
waiting for new image
```

**Update:** Updated the code to create the queue with max capacity of 1 so that the `update_image()` method thread blocks until there is enough room in the queue for the next image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that image_created.wait() is not being woken up properly in the main thread. The reason behind this is that the image creation and notification are being done inside a block with self.image_created, and this block is closed before notify_all() is called. As a result, when the asynchronous generator tries to wait on image_created.wait(), no notification has occurred.

```
def update_image(self):
    while True:
        self.image_used.clear()
        with self.image_created:
            print("create new image")
            time.sleep(0.6)
            self.image = str(random.random())
        print("notify_all")
        self.image_created.notify_all()
        print("wait for someone to take it")
        self.image_used.wait()
        print("someone took it")
```

Comment: I get the error: `RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock` on `self.image_created.notify_all()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, However, this throws the above exception. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleepen` in the `update_imagemethod` can potentially block the event loop. It is better to use await `asyncio.sleepen` instead.

The `image_generator` method must be an asynchronous generator function for async for to work correctly.

You can use `asyncio` instead. Event to signal when a new image is available.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this code and tell me if you still get the same thing? It seems you get different errors than mine.

```
class ImageUpdater:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.image_used = threading.Event()
        self.image_created = threading.Event()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def update_image(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.6)
            with self.lock:
                self.image = str(random.random())
                self.image_created.set()
                self.image_used.wait()
                self.image_created.clear()

    async def image_generator(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                self.image_created.clear()
                self.image_used.clear()
                print("waiting for new image")
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                yield self.image
                self.image_used.set()

async def main():
    updater = ImageUpdater()

    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=updater.update_image)
    update_thread.start()


    async for image in updater.image_generator():
        print(f"Received new image: {image}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This version just prints: `Received new image: None` which means that no new "image" is ever created.

Comment: If I receive images, what version of Python are you using? waiting for new image
Received new image: 0.5512548052542964

Comment: Ok, I started with python 3.10.11 which gives `None`, but python 3.11 creates one image eventually, but I couldn't wait for a second image.

Comment: What do you mean, you couldn't wait for a second image, you got it, so the problem is solved?

Comment: I later want to have several consumers, so having an event image_created that is unset by a consumer is not good, because the image generator would start and everything would run out of sync

Comment: Well, I didn't know that information, so what is your new problem?